# Calculate max value of object field after model save

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

In views.py I have this

```
class CarListView(ListView):
model = Car

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CarListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['max_price'] = Car.objects.all().aggregate(Max('price'))
    return context
```

Aggregate method will be called every time user requests the page. This will add some delay to page loading. I want this max_price variable to be calculated every time admin saved new Car objects. How to do this?

Comment: Why not just overwrite the save() method?

Comment: Ok, but how to pass this variable to template? Via sessions?

Comment: By the way, I should also rewrite `delete` method...

Comment: Why get all data? Try this Car.objects.all().only('price').aggregate(Max('price'))

Comment: Or try Car.objects.all().values('price').order_by('-price')[0] on admin

Comment: Thank you, @ArundasR! Do you suggest to use global variable to pass max data to template?

Comment: Can u check my answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance in Django is of very much importance. If you want the requirement to be implemented in ListView go for

```
Car.objects.all().only('price').aggregate(Max('price'))
```

The sql query will be

```
SELECT MAX("table_car"."price") AS "price__max" FROM "table__car"
```

Here e are not fetching all the table data and so the performance will be much better than fetching all data.

You can use

```
Car.objects.all().values('price').aggregate(Max('price'))
```

also.

If you want to get the data when admin saves the data you can do this,

```
Car.objects.all().values('price').order_by('-price')[0]
```

This orders the car data based on values and fetches only one entry

SQL query:

```
SELECT "car"."price" FROM "car" ORDER BY "car__price"."price" DESC LIMIT 1
```

These will reduce SQL query time and will improve performance.